# Ring of real sequences

Tags: ring-theory

> Let $R=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ be the ring of real sequences. Are the convergent sequences a subring of $R$? Are the convergent sequences an ideal of $R$?

Using the definition of limit for sequences  are a subring of $R$, but I don't believe they are an ideal. I would have to show the product of a non-convergent sequence with a convergent sequence not always is convergent?

Answer (score 4):

The sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$ is convergent but when you do termwise multiplication with $(1,2,3,4,\ldots)$ what do you get?

For the subring question: Recall if $\lim a_n = a$ and $\lim b_n = b$ then $\lim (a_n + b_n) = a+b$ and $\lim a_nb_n = ab$.